# LINQ2OBJECTS: Help with query. Creating a list on the fly

Tags: c#, linq, xsd, linq-to-objects

I have a class created from XML Schema. And i have the following query, the query returns well as an anonymous method

```
    var test1 = from t in test.Test
                   join p in test.Params on t.Test_Id equals p.Test_Id
                   join p1 in test.Param on p.Params_Id equals p1.Params_Id
                   select new { Name = t.Name, Params = p1};
```

It returns 4 records, because i have 2 Tests and each tests has 2 params.

I am using an anonymous type for testing. I notice in the above example Params is actually of type ParamRow.

I would like to put it into my own class that looks like this.

```
public class MyOwnClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Param> Params { get; set; }
}
```

my Param  is like this, which is included as an ILIST

```
public class Param
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

I am having an issue to create the new "PARAM" in my new class and assign Name and Enabled..

```
 Name should be assigned to p1.Name
```

and

```
 Enabled should be assigned to p1.Enabled
```

So what i need eventually is 2 records returns and each record as 2 params as an ILIST with it.

Confused :-)

Can anyone help?

Hence i should end up with

```
 Test1
    Params
       Param1
       Param2

 Test2
    Params
       Param1
       Param2
```

I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you what you want

```
var test1 = from t in test.Test
            select new MyOwnClass { 
                                   Name = t.Name, 
                                   Params = (from p in test.Params
                                             join p1 in test.Param on p.Params_Id equals p1.ParamsId
                                             where p.Test_Id == t.Test_Id
                                             select new Param {
                                                               Name = p1.Name,
                                                               Enabled = p1.Enabled
                                                              }).ToList()
                                  };
```

Comment: Thanks arturo, yes that worked... thanks.. made a note of it for the future.